# git record-only merge / whitelist known breaks from interbranch diff report

Tags: git, svn, change-management

I have an automatic report aimed at catching missing commits between release branches based on the output of

```
tgt=$(git rev-parse --verify "origin/${TARGET_BRANCH}")
ref=$(git rev-parse --verify "origin/${REFERENCE_BRANCH}")
git log --oneline --pretty=format:'%h\x1E%ad\x1E%s%d\x1E%an' --date=short --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges "${tgt}...${ref}"
```

which works nicely for 99% cases. Sometimes though, usually because of a gentle human touch post-merge/post-cherry-pick there are breaks. Which I want to "white list" post manual validation to keep the report in a clean PASS-good/FAIL-bad shape not requiring manual judgement.

With Subversion I would have just done `merge --record only -c<commit-id> ...` to shut the `svn --show-revs eligible` up.

Is there a way to do it in GIT (not storing any meta-information outside the git repository)?

Comment: BTW, have you tried using `git cherry` to list the missing commits between 2 branches?...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subversion has --record-only for merges, how do I do the same in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786272/subversion-has-record-only-for-merges-how-do-i-do-the-same-in-git)

Comment: @PhilippWendler - indeed!