# Git - How to split code in a feature branch in such a way that future merges/rebases from master don't remove the code from the feature branch

Tags: git

We decided that part of our functionality is only good for a specific subset of our clients, so we decided to "split out" this code into a feature branch.

The code is already in master and we need to create the feature branch, then remove the code from master.

The problem is, what would happen later, when we need to merge/rebase new functionality from master to the feature branch? By what I tested, future merges will remove this code from the feature branch as well, but I want to retain that code in the branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subversion has --record-only for merges, how do I do the same in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786272/subversion-has-record-only-for-merges-how-do-i-do-the-same-in-git)

Comment: Assuming you only deliver built executables and not code, have you considered just keeping this functionality in the main codebase and making it switchable, either at compile-time (e.g. two builds, one that includes it and one that doesn't) or at run-time (e.g. a plug-in framework)?

Comment: Be careful not to do this too often, or you'll end up in maintenance hell, taking care of one branch per client. It's generaly a bad idea to solve things like this via branches, better keep things together in the main codebase as @Matthew Strawbridge noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is the following: create the feature branch only after the deletion in master, and use `git revert` to resurrect the code in the feature branch. This should be done soon after the removal in order to avoid conflicts.

Comment: That did exactly what I needed and it also made it obvious in the branch history what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a long winded way but you could:

- create a temporary feature branch to store the current code
- Remove the code from master
- create the correct feature branch from master
- merge or re-add the code from the temporary feature branch into the main feature branch

From there, any development work/bug fixes would be done from master and merged into the branch with this feature in order to keep it up to date.

Alternatively, look to see if there is a way you can turn this feature on or off per customer, and have the functionality available for all customers, but only enabled for the ones who want it.